# Asynchronous Process doesn't seem to work on my prod environment

Tags: php, symfony, asynchronous, process, command

I'm currently working on a rather complex PHP5/Symfony 2.8 project. In this project, I have a command that can be called by a Crontab, manually in console, or using a button on the website, that is used to call a webservice on an external site, which gives me an xml file, that I manage to import into my database using SimpleXML.

The command works like a charm on my local dev environment, no matter how it is called.

But for unknown reasons (which is why I'm posting here), on my int or prod environments, which are located on external servers, calling the command from the button on the site isn't working.

My button is triggering this action :

```
$process = new Process('php '.$kernelRootDir.'/console my:super:command');
$process->start();
```

As the command is kinda heavy, I can not afford to wait for the command to be completed, which is why I'm using process->start rather than run. I'm not in need of logs for it, so that's fine that it just starts the command and let it run while the user can go on another page.

And again, this works great on my local environment (debian 7 VM), but not on the distant server (not sure what it is using). However, if I manually launch the command via console or let the crontab call it, it runs perfectly until the end. That's just triggering it from my controller via Process that doesn't work.

This is pulling my hair off my head since yesterday, but I can't figure out why the command isn't even starting on the prod environment.. Any tips ?

Update : Tried to make my command only dumping a small "it worked" message, and using wait() and getOutput() methods to get the result in my controller. On my local environment, I instantly got my message as a result from the controller using dump/die combo. On the distant server, my command trigger a ProcessTimedOutException : the process exceeded the 60 seconds timeout.

So there is really a problem with Process being unable to launch a custom command, though that command works when called manually on console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, after struggling since two days, I found that the distant server might be responsible of this, it seems that if I don't wait for the process answer, that process is killed instantly. I don't know why, I don't know how, but it seems like it is.

So I started searching for an alternative solution that was not using Process. And I found something. I can use the php exec() method to launch an asynchronous call by doing so :

```
exec('php '.$kernelRootDir.'/console my:super:command > /dev/null &');
//Apparently, using "&" launch the command asynchronously.
```

All my tests have been working on my production server so far, so I'll keep that.